# Plotly add dropdown in graph to show multiple graphs

Tags: python, graph, plotly, dropdown

I have plotted 4 types of graphs, `bar`,`scatter`,`pie`,`sunburst` for a dataset.

```
data=winner_list
plot = px.bar(winner_list,x="Team",y="Win_count")
plot.show()
```

when i use the following code, i cannot view the multiple graphs in dropdown, only the first graph is visible

```
#to give dropdown for plots

plot.update_layout(

    updatemenus=[

        dict(

            buttons=list([
                dict(
                    args=["type", "pie"],
                    label="Bar Chart",
                    method="restyle"
                ),
                dict(
                    args=["type", "scatter"],
                     label="s chart",
                    method="restyle"
                ),
                 dict(
                    args=["type", "fig14"],
                     label="P chart",
                    method="restyle"
                )
            ]),
            direction="down",
        ),
    ]
)

 plot.show()
```

how can i place a dropdown in the graph, so that i can view different plots

Comment: I dont understand - dropdown is for displaying list with strings, not plots. And it needs to execute some function to change content on page - so you would have to assign function (callback) to dropdown.

Comment: better create minimal working code which we could copy and run - and then we can use it for tests and solutions.

Comment: @hari in order for us to better help you, you should give us a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). we don't know what your `winner_list` data looks like so we can't run your code. can you copy and paste the output from `winner_list.head().to_dict()` into your question?

Comment: this is the output of winner_list.head()
 Team Win_count Total_matches

0 Chennai Super Kings 100 164

1 Deccan Chargers 29 75

2 Delhi Capitals 10 16

3 Delhi Daredevils 67 159

4 Gujarat Lions 13 30

Comment: @hari can you include the output from `winner_list.head().to_dict()` in your question? it should be a dictionary so I can copy it and use it